# Elasticseach : "type" : "mapper_parsing_exception"

Tags: elasticsearch

I am new to elasticseach and trying to implement small assignment for my own learning prospect.
I am referring https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/dynamic-templates.html link to create a dynamic template; however while running the query mentioned below I am getting  "type" : "mapper_parsing_exception",   "reason" : "Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters: error .

Can someone please assist me with the error? looks like I haven't defined my template name in proper place .

```
PUT e_review_dynamictemplate
{
  "mappings": {
    "date_detection": true,
    "dynamic_date_formats": ["dd/MM/yyyy"], 
    "numeric_detection": true, 
    "My_dynamic_templates": [
      {
      "e_full_name": {
          "path_match":   "*_Name",
          "mapping": {
            "type":       "text",
            "copy_to":    "e_full_name",
            "norms": false
          }
        },
      "integers": {
          "match_mapping_type": "long",
          "mapping": {
            "type": "integer",
            "index": false
          }
        },
      "strings": {
         "match_mapping_type": "string",
         "match":   "Achievements:*",
         "unmatch": "Improvements:*",
          "mapping": {
            "type": "long"
          }
        }
      }
      ]
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance!
Nivedita

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you just missed the `dynamic_templates` properties in the `mappings` object. You just have to replace `My_dynamic_templates` by `dynamic_templates`.

The custom names are used in template definitions inside the `dynamic_templates` array.

Here is the corrected snippet :

```
PUT e_review_dynamictemplate
{
  "mappings": {
    "date_detection": true,
    "dynamic_date_formats": [
      "dd/MM/yyyy"
    ],
    "numeric_detection": true,
    "dynamic_templates": [
      {
        "e_full_name": {
          "path_match": "*_Name",
          "mapping": {
            "type": "text",
            "copy_to": "e_full_name",
            "norms": false
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "integers": {
          "match_mapping_type": "long",
          "mapping": {
            "type": "integer",
            "index": false
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "strings": {
          "match_mapping_type": "string",
          "match": "Achievements:*",
          "unmatch": "Improvements:*",
          "mapping": {
            "type": "long"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Pierre Mallet

Comment: @NiveditaK if your problem is solved, could you accept the answer to close your question ? Thanks

Comment: Yes , my problem is solved.